# Wait for an mpsc channel to have messages without receiving any message

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio

In my mind, this problem should be trivial to solve, but after some searching I am still unable to do this. I have a `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver` (let us call it `receiver`). I would like to wait for `receiver` to have messages in it, without however pulling any message out. Having looked at the [docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html), I cannot find anything other than `receiver.recv()` to get the job done, which however pulls the first message out. I cannot seem to find anything along the lines of `receiver.readable()` or `receiver.peek()` or anything like that. Am I missing something? Is there a workaround to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are right. You may consider using a second channel.

If you are not interested in the value (like with `readable`) you can send to both channels at the same time, one passing the actual data, and one passing simply the unit (`()`) just to signal there is something happening.

If you do want to see the value (like with `peek`), another approach may be sending the data to the first channel as usual, and sending the data into the second channel directly after receiving it in the first.

Answer (score 1):

Current implementation has a semaphore inside which really has what you need, but interface does not expose it. As a workaround, you can use some other implementation, not from tokio. [Here is an example](https://docs.rs/flume/latest/flume/struct.Receiver.html#) which is sync+async and has [is_empty](https://docs.rs/flume/latest/flume/struct.Receiver.html#method.is_empty) function which works like you need.